# Jackson Timestamp parse string

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jackson

I received this date string `2017-12-16T14:06:01.49291` from postgresql `json_build_object` function and i used the following in my object:

```
@JsonProperty("creation_date")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private Timestamp creationDate;
```

when parsing i received the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.sql.Timestamp` from String "2017-12-16T14:06:01.49291": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

Any idea on how to parse such string inside jackson

Answer (score 0):

I used this pattern

```
 @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
```

and it worked, but I still think there is a better solution.